# Memory leaks in "dojox/mvc/Output"

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, dojo, dijit.form

Is there a best practice to clean dojo widgets of type "dojox/mvc/Output" ? My output widgets of such type have data-dojo-props such as innerHTML but am unable to figure out the root cause of memory leaks. Is there a general best-practice around this specific kind of widget?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to clean-up dojox/mvc/Output seems the same as [one for regular widgets](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#lifecycle). If it does not solve the problem, you may wan to try dijit/_WidgetBase instead, like: `<span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" data-dojo-props="_setInnerTextAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'}, innerText: at(model, 'prop')"></span>`.